# Leaflet JS - Issues on max zoomin

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am posting this because I would like to resolve two issues with my map that are ruining the user experience. My goal is to have these issues resolved and will be outlined below.

[image: The Issue at hand]

1. The bubbles, red and blue, are overlapping. I have tried to increase the maxClusterRadius from 80 to 200 in my options but I have not noticed any change. There was no error message. What I would like is to have the bubbles offset from one another, with the blue circle appearing at the top left.
2. When I click the bubbles at this level of zoom, they spread out/spiderfy as in the middle of the screenshot. I do not want click events on these bubbles at this level of zoom that portrays the information this way. I have tried editing options but I have not been able to get it to work.

Please let me know if you require further details and I shall post them below.

Thanks.

Comment: You are providing no code to see, so I'm going to *assume* you're using [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/), and that you have two instances of `MarkerClusterGroup`, one for red, one for blue (please clarify!!). If that's the case, the approach would be setting [`iconAnchor`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#icon-iconanchor) on ['iconCreateFunction'](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/#customising-the-clustered-markers) as desired; alternatively, put everything in one cluster and ad more complex symbolization.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you for continually helping me out. I have noticed your name repeatedly. 

I am using Leaflet.marketcluster. It's actually one function.

Comment: It'll be better if you show enough code for a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'll absolutely try my best to do so. The code base is massive though. and the data I am using is private. It might not be possible given privacy and my skill level.

What I've done for now is reduce the minimum zoom so they no longer overlap. I am stuck on the spiderfying issue now.